# Entity Framework Include

Tags: .net, entity-framework

If I want to include navigation propeties of two levels, it it enough to `Inlcude("Navigation1.Navigation2")` or should I explicitly add the first level `Include("Navigation1")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try it? `Inlcude("Navigation1.Navigation2")` is enough.